# PHP Speedier Alternatives?

Tags: php

I have been working on code that essentially is a sort of a web crawler, that goes to a certain site and grabs the different desired sections, giving me links, which I then go to those links and grab the desired parts of them, parsing it to an array. The issue is that there are 54 sections, with the different parts I want totaling up to about 8,500 items.

The big issue is that working with all of this, and given the fact that I can not personally change the code of the sites, I am left with a pretty slow load time on my page when I am working with the loops. I was wondering if anyone here could see any place that may speed up my code at all, any little bit would help.
I have already gotten an average load time of about 21 seconds to about 16 seconds from switching from for loops to the xpath queries, but to me, it still seems pretty slow.

Anyways, here is the code. I have generalized it.

(When benchmarking, I have found that the newPart section finishes with an average of about (.00004 seconds). I don't believe this is where it slows down, however this is the part where there is 8,500 times it runs, so if you can find a way to speed that up, that would be wonderful as well.)

```
$sections = array();
// Here is some bs website, just as an example.
$homepage = "google.com";
function getSections() {
    global $homePage;

    $options = array('http'=>array('method'=>"GET", "headers'=>'User-Agent: ACrawler/1.0\n"));
    $contex = stream_context_create($options);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML(@file_get_contents($homePage, false, $contex));

    $query = "//div[contains(@class, 'col-md-8 uw-content')]/ul/li/a";
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $result = $xpath->query($query);

    foreach($result as $a){
        $link = $a->getAttribute("href");
        $name = "";
        $text = $a->textContent;
        $etext = explode(" ", $text);
        for($i = 1; $i < count($etext); $i++){
            if(substr($etext[$i], 0, 1) == "(") {
                if(substr($etext[$i], -1) == ")")
                    $name .= substr($etext[$i], 1, -1)." ";
                else
                    $name .= substr($etext[$i], 1)." ";
            } else if(substr($etext[$i], -1) == ")") {
                $name .= substr($etext[$i], 0, -1);
            }
        }
        if(substr($name, -1) == " ")
            $name = substr($name, 0, -1);
        getParts($link, $name);
    }
}

function getParts($newlink, $name) {
    global $homePage, $sections;

    $options = array('http'=>array('method'=>"GET", "headers'=>'User-Agent: ACrawler/1.0\n"));
    $contex = stream_context_create($options);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $link = $homePage.$newlink;
    @$doc->loadHTML(@file_get_contents($link, false, $contex));

    $newSection = array();
    $parts = array();

    $newSection["sectionName"] = $name;

    $query = "//a[@name]";
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $result = $xpath->query($query);

    foreach($result as $a){
        $newPart = newPart($a, $name);
        $parts[] = $newPart;
    }

    $newSection["parts"] = $parts;
    $sections[] = $newSection;
}

function newPart($a, $name){
    $newPart = array();
    $p = $a->getElementsByTagName("p")[0];

    $title = $p->getElementsByTagName("b")[0]->textContent;
    $splitTitle = explode(" ", $title);
    $number = null;
    $cleared = null;
    if(is_numeric($splitTitle[1])){
        $number = $splitTitle[1];
        $cleared = 2;
    }else{
        $number = $splitTitle[2];
        $cleared = 3;
    }

    $pname = "";
    $ints = null;
    $categories = array();

    for($i = $cleared; $i < count($splitTitle); $i++)
        if($splitTitle[$i][0] != "(")
            if($ints != null)
                if(substr($splitTitle[$i], -1) == ",")
                    $categories[] = substr($splitTitle[$i], 0, -1);
                else
                    $categories[] = $splitTitle[$i];
            else
                $pname .= $splitTitle[$i]." ";
        else
            $ints = $splitTitle[$i][1];

    $description = "";
    $splitdesc = "";
    $text = $p->textContent;
    $splitText = explode(" ", $text);
    // -8 for View course details in YYYYYY: X XXXX XXX
    $sentences = array();
    $sentence = "";
    for($i = count($splitTitle) - 1; $i < count($splitText) - (5 + $cleared - 1); $i++)
        if(substr($splitText[$i], -1) == "."){
            $sentence .= $splitText[$i];
            $sentences[] = $sentence;
            $sentence = "";
        }else if(substr($splitText[$i], -5) == ".View"){
            $sentence .= $splitText[$i];
            $sentence = substr($sentence, 0, -4);
            $sentences[] = $sentence;
            $sentence = "";
        }else
            if($i == count($splitTitle) - 1)
                $sentence .= substr($splitText[$i], 3)." ";
            else
                $sentence .= $splitText[$i]." ";
    $splitdesc = array();
    if(count($sentences) != 0){
        while(substr($sentences[count($sentences) - 1], 0, 11) == "Prerequisite" ||
            substr($sentences[count($sentences) - 1], 0, 11) == "Co-requisite"){
            $splitdesc[] = $sentences[count($sentences) - 1];
            unset($sentences[count($sentences) - 1]);
        }
        for($i = count($splitdesc); $i > 0; $i--)
            $splitdesc.= $splitdesc[$i]." ";
        foreach($sentences as $sentence)
            $description .= $sentence." ";
    }

    $link = $p->getElementsByTagName("a")[0]->getAttribute("href");

    $newClass["number"] = $number;
    $newClass["title"] = $pname;
    $newClass["ints"] = $ints;
    $newClass["categories"] = $categories;
    $newClass["description"] = $description;
    $newClass["splitdesc"] = $splitdesc;
    $newClass["link"] = $link;

    return $newClass;
}

getSections();
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I guess everything except `file_get_contents` is quite quick. Could you please benchmark just this row. And also do some benchmarks with and without the error suppression operator!

Comment: Do you need to crawl the data for all 8500 items? Maybe you can just crawl the titles/links and when accessing an item you crawl the details?

Comment: @csabinho Thanks for taking a look. I got a speed of about half a second with the error suppression and about .35 seconds with a few errors. Would there be some way faster that you could think of?

Comment: @JimL I would be interested in trying that. However, I am filtering the items by some of the other details. I think that provides an issue when parsing some information, then getting other information later. But I still want to ponder the idea a little more before I make a definite decision. Thanks for the idea

Comment: Why not use threads?

Comment: It's the *latency* of your `file_get_contents()` processing that kills performance because you pay all those tens/hundreds of milliseconds one after the other sequentially. The answer is to be doing 32, 64 or 128 requests in parallel. Either use threads, or stuff all the URLs to fetch in a workpile and set a bunch of workers on them.

Comment: @MarkSetchell How would I use threads in order to read a website. So far, off of what I can find, threads are used to add more to websites, instead of reading them.

Comment: Try opening an editor and making a file with 32 or more lines in it, each one being a URL that you want to fetch using, say, `curl`. Then time a `bash` loop that reads and fetches each URL. Then use **GNU Parallel** to get 32 in parallel at a time `parallel -j32 -a URLs.txt curl`. Then you'll see you pay all the latency hits in parallel, rather than one after the other.